# How do I enchant a bow with Mending and Infinity?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In *Minecraft: Xbox One Edition*, I wanted to make a bow with Unbreaking III, Flame I, Infinity I, Power V, Punch II, and Mending I, but it won't let me add Mending I. Why won't it allow me to make such a bow?

Comment: Please clarify what you have already tried in detail.

Comment: Are you really playing [Minecraft:Xbox One Edition](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Xbox_One_Edition), a game that was discontinued in 2017?

Answer (score 12):

Infinity and Mending are mutually exclusive, meaning that they cant be on the same bow. You can only pick one between infinite arrows and infinite durability.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to play in version 1.8. I believe in that time you were actually able to get both Infinity and Mending on one bow, but it has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

go into version 1.9 enchant the bow to have infinity and mending, then quit and go into whatever version you want. when you load that world you will have the bow. to get it into other worlds utilize the hotbar save function and save it to it. open the bookshelf button in creative and it should be there for other worlds.

Comment: please re read the entire question. this answer does not work

Answer (score -2):

A skeleton horseman may RARELY drop a bow enchanted with both infinity and mending, but since skeleton horsemen are already so rare and hard to kill, it's almost impossible.

Tips for obtaining the bow:
Skeleton horses may spawn during thunderstorms, prepare yourself with a full set of armour, an enchanted bow and a sword (ideally enchanted with smite and looting). As you approach the skeleton horse, lighting will strike it again and spawn four skeleton horsemen equipped with iron helmets and enchanted bows, kill the riders but DO NOT KILL THE SKELETON HORSES as it is passive and ridable by you. Then if the skeletons are happy they with drop their bow(s).

Comment: This is not possible. Mending and Infinity are incompatible.

Comment: I did some testing myself.. skeleton horsemen will only ever drop bows with power I, unbreaking I, or both.. they won't even drop with infinity or mending.. this is coming from the drops of over 1000 skeleton horsemen. It's impossible via this method.. I also don't believe regular skeletons can spawn with them.. nor do I think one can be fished by chance.. I really do think the devs tied up all loose ends.. it might simply be impossible without commands.

Answer (score -3):

There are 2 methods of doing this. The first one is to fish almost 7000 times and hope for one. The other way is to try to kill skeletons for them.